# Display an email I just sent

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to display an email I just sent. The idea is that when I send an email, and the email appears in the Sent folder in Outlook, it will automatically open.

The code below creates an email instead of opening mail newly arrived in the Sent folder.

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace

    Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set SentItems = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
End Sub

Private Sub sentItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    Dim FirstPos, LastPos As Long
    Dim DirectoryLine As String
    Dim myOlMItem As Outlook.MailItem

    On Error GoTo Handler

    Set Item = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objOutlookMsg = Item.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    objOutlookMsg.Display
```

Comment: If your `sentItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)` event is working, you may simply use `Item.Display` to open the sent item. No need using `.CreateItem` at all

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a new item, use the one passed as a parameter:

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace

  Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
  Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set SentItems = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
End Sub

Private Sub sentItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
  Item.Display
End Sub
```